# unable to add a vm to an Availability Set in azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I just created a standard vm inside Azure, and created a new Availability set.
  I created another vm, with the same specs, in the same region, but when I go to configurare the availability set I don't see it in the list.
  I'm missing something?

Luca

Comment: Did you set up the new VM in the same Cloud Service as the first VM, or in a new Cloud Service?

Comment: what you mean for same cloud service? same datacenter? I tried both inside the same region than another region

Comment: *Same cloud service* means both VMs are in the same `xxx.cloudapp.net` container. This is not about region. This option is presented on the 3rd page of the New VM wizard, when filling out the fields.

Comment: thank you very much. I was using the quick create and I haven't seen the additional parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So... just posting this as an answer, to properly close the loop based on the comments under the question:

When setting up a Virtual Machine, you can choose which *Cloud Service* to place the Virtual Machine in. The Cloud Service is essentially a container which gets assigned a specific IP address, gets a `cloudapp.net` name (e.g. `myservice.cloudapp.net`), and gets assigned to a region (or affinity group, which is region-specific).

Availability Sets are specific to a given Cloud Service. You may place any of your Cloud Service's VMs in the same Availability Set (or even have multiple Availability Sets, with groups of VMs assigned to specific Availability Sets). However: An Availability Set does *not* span across Cloud Services.

So: When you went to set up your second Virtual Machine, and you didn't see your Availability Set, that is because you were attempting to deploy to a different Cloud Service.

Answer (score 1):

Below screenshot shows the wizard page where we can select existing cloud service to which we can associate a new VM

[image: Below screenshot shows the wizard page where we can select existing cloud service to which we can associate a new VM]